# Personally upgrading PHP version from 5.2.x to 5.3.x

Tags: php, shared-hosting

My current local hosting company is unwilling to upgrade my PHP version to 5.3.x as they are afraid it may cause problem to their other customers.

I've seen online that we may be able to upgrade it ourselves. One suggestion is to use WHM that we can access at `domain.com:2087` but unfortunately the hosting company is not giving their customers access to this.

Are there any other alternatives? The only access that they are giving me is the cPanel at `domain.com:2083`.

Comment: You can't upgrade it unless you own a hosting server.

Comment: only thing may be affect that some functions are deprecated in 5.3 which might be problem here is list of them http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php

Comment: @tepkenvannkorn yes you can. I for one can upgrade PHP on my shared host whenever I please and I do not have root access either. I just compile PHP however I want as CGI and then setup .htaccess file to use it. I just compiled PHP 5.5alpha4 and it's working fine. I'm sure it depends on the host, but any host that allows compiling and uses CGI should work fine.

Comment: @NullPointer yeah i want to upgrade it to at least 5.3.x as that was the minimum requirement of joomla 3.

Comment: @crypticツ any detailed instructions on how to do this?

Comment: @NullPointer im working for a client now and we have decided to start using joomla 3 to avoid future problem if we stick on joomla 2.5 and if we continue to rely on the php5.2.x as currently offered by the hosting server. we understand that eventually the php will be upgraded but just dont know when. so thats why we want to work on the latest version available.

Comment: @ImpStudent All the tutorials I could find online involve all these extra steps. I made a Bash script to automate it all for me. I can pastebin it for you, but you will be responsible for making sure all the paths and config settings are changed for your setup which would involve knowing some Bash and commandline. But once setup you can run the script whenever to compile a new version. I can't guarantee this will work on your host, but it's worth a try. Also host must be running PHP as CGI for you to be able to use your own CGI.

Comment: @crypticツ Discussed this with my client and they have decided to go for other international hostings instead. Thanks for your input and thanks to everyone else too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't upgrade PHP if you do not have root access to the box. The only way to do it is to get your own box at home, colocate at a datacentre, or a rent a VPS/small dedicated server.

Comment: @DannyBeckett see my above comment, this is not always true. There are ways around it.

Comment: @DannyBeckett when you mentioned root access, does that mean having access to the highest folder in the ftp where we can see directories such as php, perl, public_html, etc? or is it further up?

Comment: @ImpStudent It's "further up". Your username would be called `root`; you'd know if you had access.